# Passing a value of <xsl:value-of> to a java script function

Tags: javascript, xslt

I want to do this job:

I have an xml file and I want to transform it with xslt in to an HTML file. It is look like this:

```
<article id="3526">
    <name>Orange</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">15.97</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa.k</lieferant>
  </article>
```

I want to show the `lieferant` on an HTML file. if the user click on the name an alert should be appear and shoes the `preis`.

I dont know, how to pass the value of `preis` into the java script code. I tried to write a very simple code to only show the `lieferant` with javascript alert, but I could not do that. could you please help me to solve this problem:

```
 <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
          function simfunc(msg)
          {
            alert(msg);
          }
        </xsl:script>
        </head>
      <xsl:for-each select="//artikel">
        <div>
          <p id='p1'  >
            <xsl:value-of select="user:simfunc(lieferant)"/>
          </p>     
        </div>
        <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that while some XSLT processors like Microsoft's MSXML support the use of extension function implemented in JScript inside of XSLT you simply have access to the objects and methods the JScript engine implements. `alert` is not a JScript function, it is a function exposed to JScript inside of the browser.

So there is no `alert` available in JScript extension functions to XSLT, you have the objects, functions and methods documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.84%29.aspx.

To give you an example, http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013072701.xml is an XML document referencing an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that with Mozilla uses some EXSLT extension function and that with IE uses an extension function implemented in JScript.

The stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013072701.xsl is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:user="http://example.com/user"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
  extension-element-prefixes="ms"
  exclude-result-prefixes="user ms regexp"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
          function simfunc(msg)
          {
            return msg.replace(/^Fa./, '');
          }
</ms:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html lang="de">
    <head>
      <title>Beispiel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Beispiel</h1>

      <xsl:for-each select="//artikel">
        <div>
          <p id="{generate-id()}">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="function-available('regexp:replace')">
                <xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(lieferant, '^Fa\.', '', '')"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="function-available('user:simfunc')">
                <xsl:value-of select="user:simfunc(string(lieferant))"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="lieferant"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </p>     
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your complete answer. As I understand it is not posible to hove `<script type=text/javascript> function firstfun{ alert(Hallo);}</script>` in the XSL file and then invoke this java script function or pass it a value, Is it correct?

Comment: `<script type="text/javacript"></script>` is how you use script in HTML or SVG. If your XSLT generates HTML or SVG you can of course use script in the generated HTML or SVG. If you want to use script in the XSLT code itself then some XSLT processors support that, in the browser world IE uses MSXML as the XSLT processor and that supports using JScript or VBScript, the way I show in my sample (for JScript). But you get access to the objects and functions the script engine implements and offers. `alert` is a function exposed by the browser, not the script engine so you don't have access to it.